# Component valuechange function get's triggerd twice

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui-angular2

I have this loop in my template that creates a kendo dropdown

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="definitionDetails.Groupings" let-i="index">
    <div *ngIf="max-1 >= i && (definitionDetails.Groupings[i-1] || i === 0)"class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 marginbottom-15 right">
        {{ i }}
        <kendo-combobox [data]="data"
                        [textField]="'Name'"
                        [valueField]="'Type'"
                        [(value)]="definitionDetails.Groupings[i]"
                        (valueChange)="groupingValueChangeHandler($event, i)">

        </kendo-combobox>
        <span *ngIf="definitionDetails.Groupings[1]">
            <i class="fa clickable group-descending"
               aria-hidden="true"
               [class.fa-sort-alpha-asc]="!definitionDetails.Groupings[i].Descending"
               [class.fa-sort-alpha-desc]="definitionDetails.Groupings[i].Descending"
               (click)="groupingDescendingChangeHandler(1)">

            </i>
        </span>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

The dropdown has a `(valueChange)` but for some reaon it gets triggered twice in a row. `(valueChange)` executes this function:

```
public groupingValueChangeHandler(value: any, i: number) {
    console.log(value);
    console.log(i);
    if (typeof value === "undefined") {
        if (i === 0) {               
            i = 1;
        }
        this.definitionDetails.Groupings.length = i;
    }
}
```

In my console I can see that this is happening:
[image]

So for some reason it get's triggerd a second time with an undefined value.

How can I fix this issue and get rid of the second trigger?

Comment: Could you share a runnable demo? A plunkr or Github repo. Thus other members could debug on-site and find the cause much easier.

Comment: Another thing to check is how many times you have included your TS file on the page..